# How to build Right to Left Push menu in Dojo Mobile

Tags: dojo, pushviewcontroller

[Example](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/)

Can some one help me out how to develop a push menu in dojo mobile like facebook and Blueprints. I have created similar in jQueryMobile but still not succeded in Dojo Mobile.

Comment: Need more detail, not sure what you mean by push menu, are talking about a slide-in pane?

Comment: I am talking about similar like on this link: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/ 
Here you can see Hide show menu. I am looking for something like this have done this in jQueryMobile but now requirements are in Dojo.

Comment: I am looking exactly like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nateflink/NWHjB/

Comment: Slide-in pane which control from a button on header I want to show menus on this pane.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

https://github.com/dmandrioli/sidepane.git